# Salesforce Oauth Status Code 302

Tags: salesforce, oauth-2.0, httpresponse

While trying to setup oauth in the org, getting status code 302.
Below is the code snippet.

```
String AUTH_URL   = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize';
String redirect_uri = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success';
String response_type = 'token';
String client_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx';

authURL = AUTH_URL + 
         '?response_type=' + response_type + 
         '&client_id=' + client_id + 
         '&redirect_uri=' + redirect_uri;

HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
Http http = new Http(); 

req.setMethod('GET'); 
req.setEndpoint(authUrl);   
res = http.send(req);
```

//RESULT:
res.getStatusCode() = 302
res.getStatus() = Found

I am expecting to receive access Token and refresh token in response's body but it is empty.
Please suggest if I am missing out on something.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the authorize endpoint is for a browser based interactive login, not a programatic login. If you want a pure programatic method, then you should checkout the username/password oauth flow that you can use via the /services/oauth2/token endpoint.

Comment: thanks for the help. We were reluctant to use username/ pass flow as we did not want to expose sf user creds. But it seems a Last Resort though. Thanks again. Cheers